# Implement MEE6 bot custom graphics in my own bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I noticed that the MEE6 bot has these cool custom pictures (well, not really pictures, graphics, maybe, but whatever). If you don't know what I'm talking about, take a look.

[image: mee6 bar]

Notice here that the text and icons are different for each user. More importantly, they implemented this into an "image". How would I do this (if it's possible)?

I would want to use this in discord.js, as a command. Don't worry about the command handler, I have it ready. Please present your ideas in module.exports = {} form. Thank you!

EDIT: Oh yeah, I know there's such thing as embeds. However, you can't implement a user's icon in embeds, nor do they have different fonts (I think?). Do I have to import any packages for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [canvacord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvacord) makes making a rank-card really easy. It's even built into canvacord! (See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvacord#rank-card))

If you want more control over how it looks, you're able to make it yourself wit for example [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

*(Little note for Phúc Lộc Nguyễn, that doesn't look like javascript at all, more like python, so I don't know what your intention was..)*